# Using Typescript 2 @Types with typescript 1.8.10

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, typescript-typings

Currently i'm trying to use d3-drag v4 types in my project.
were using Ts 1.8.10 and not ready to move to the TS2 beta.

the d3-v4 typings library is located here:
https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped

i tried to install the typings using:

```
typings install d3-drag=github:tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/src/d3-drag/index.d.ts#4d09073c046b6444859c66ff441f1e7691777d0f --save
```

but i'm getting the following error:

> typings ERR! caused by 
>   /tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/47eae6d/src/d3-selection.d.ts
>   responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

i found somebody asking the same question here:

https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/issues/93

but it doesn't answer my problem because i cant migrate to ts2 just yet.
is there anyway using @types with TS 1.8.10?

Comment: This seems like a bug / unexpected feature in the url parsing of `typings`. I would consider opening an issue on the typings github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meanwhile i created a d.ts file to be able to use drag.
 no intellisense and no type check, but at least i can use the drag library.

```
 declare var d3Drag;
 declare module 'd3-drag' 
{ 
export = d3Drag;
 }
```

I use it in my code like this:

```
import * as d3Drag from 'd3-drag';

...
let dragBehaivor = d3Drag.drag().on("start", dragStartFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire the necessary files with

```
npm install @types/d3-selection --save
```

That will put the definition folder in node_modules/@types.  You should then be able to copy the d3-selection folder to the typings folder and add the reference  to the index.d.ts file there.  I haven't tried it because I am moving to TS2, but it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it is unfortunately not possible to use @types for D3 with TypeScript 1.8.x. For two reasons:

1. The entire definitions/module resolution the TS2 compiler performs to use definitions installed from npm @types is not available in TS 1.8.x
2. The definitions you are referring to https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped have now been migrated to the DefinitelyTyped/types-2.0 branch. They are the ones feeding @types for `@types/d3` (Standard D3 v4 Bundle), `@types/d3-selection`, `@types/d3-drag` etc. All of them where written in a definition module structure only supported as of TS 2. They also use other TS features, like `this` typing of function contexts.

For these two reasons they will not be viable for TS 1.8.

Hopefully, you have been able to upgrade since you originally posted, since TS 2 is no longer beta.